# Ajax response displaying multiple times on every click

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have two dropdowns and I am displaying first dynamically by clicking on the `Add More` button and second, it will call the ajax and display. I mean When I click on the `Add more` button then it will also call the Ajax and get the output and it will display the second dropdown. This is also working.

But I am getting one issue. Now the issue is, When I click the first time on the `Add more` button then it will call the ajax and display the dropdown. When I click on the second time the I am getting two dropdowns from ajax. When I click on the third time the I am getting three dropdowns from ajax and it continues repeating Like below image. I have to display only one dropdown which will come from the ajax. I shared my script code below.

[image]

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
  var maxField = 10; //Input fields increment limitation
  var x = 1; //Initial field counter is 1
  var count = 2;
  var numberIncr = 1; // used to increment the name for the inputs
  var addrm = '';

  //Once add button is clicked
  $(document).on('click', '#clicktoadd', function() {
    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    async: false,
    url: "/access_control/getname",
    //data: {},
    dataType: 'json',

    success: function(response) {

      addrm += '<select name="addrm' + numberIncr + '" class="form-control multipleselect dynamicVal"><option value="" selected disabled>Select</option>';
      $.each(response, function(key, data) {
        addrm += '<option value="' + data.rmid + '">' + data.rmfirstname + ' ' + data.rmlastname + '</option>';
        //rm_details.push(addrm);
      });
      addrm += '</select>';
    }
  });
    var innercoutner = $(this).closest('.medication_info').find('.medication_info').children('.row').length+2;
    //Check maximum number of input fields
    if (x < maxField) {
      x++; //Increment field counter
      numberIncr++;
      $(".medication_info").append('<input type="text" name="pp_order'+numberIncr+'" value="'+c+'-' + inner(innercoutner, 2) + '" class="form-control event_stop dynamicVal"><select name="pp_fileStatus' + numberIncr + '" class="form-control multipleselect pp_fileStatus dynamicVal"><option value="" disabled selected>Status</option><option value="1">Open</option><option value="2">Close</option><option value="3">Pending</option></select>' + addrm);
    }
    count++;

  });
});
```

Comment: `addrm` should be a local variable in the `click` handler, not a global variable. It's remembering the value from the previous click and adding to it.

Comment: @Barmar, Right that is local variable. How can I solve that. Do i make it global?

Comment: You should not be using a synchronous call either

Comment: @epascarello, Do I need to add async: false in ajax?

Answer (score 1):

Make `addrm` a local variable, so it doesn't remember the content from the previous call.

And the code at the bottom that appends to `.medication_info` needs to be inside the `success:` function.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var maxField = 10; //Input fields increment limitation
  var x = 1; //Initial field counter is 1
  var count = 2;
  var numberIncr = 1; // used to increment the name for the inputs

  //Once add button is clicked
  $(document).on('click', '#clicktoadd', function() {
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "/access_control/getname",
      //data: {},
      dataType: 'json',

      success: function(response) {

        var addrm = '<select name="addrm' + numberIncr + '" class="form-control multipleselect dynamicVal"><option value="" selected disabled>Select</option>';
        $.each(response, function(key, data) {
          addrm += '<option value="' + data.rmid + '">' + data.rmfirstname + ' ' + data.rmlastname + '</option>';
          //rm_details.push(addrm);
        });
        addrm += '</select>';
        //Check maximum number of input fields
        if (x < maxField) {
          x++; //Increment field counter
          numberIncr++;
          $(".medication_info").append('<select name="pp_fileStatus' + numberIncr + '" class="form-control multipleselect pp_fileStatus dynamicVal"><option value="" disabled selected>Status</option><option value="1">Open</option><option value="2">Close</option><option value="3">Pending</option></select>' + addrm);
        }
        count++
      }

    });
  });
});
```

There's also no need for `async: false`.

Comment: Please alter your code to make the Ajax call the right way. Save the planet from synchronous calls.

Comment: @Barmar, but when I click on button then I am getting ReferenceError: addrm is not defined in console

Comment: I moved that code into the `success` function so it has access to the variable.

Comment: I think some bracket is missing in your anser.

Comment: Fixed it. That's what happens when I use the SO editor instead of a real IDE.

Comment: @Barmar, Yes, It's working but If I add   .medication_info append function inside success then I am getting the increment in the numberIncr. Like addrm1 then addrm3 if click again the addrm5

Comment: I don't see how that's happening. It only increments `numberIncr` once each time it gets an ajax response.

Comment: Try adding console log calls to see when the function is being called.

Comment: @Barmar, Yes, your answer is working, there was some issue from my side which I corrected. but I notice one more error. Like I have on the input field and I am getting that undefied after adding the code inside success. I added in the question

Comment: I checked in consolve. Every time I am getting 2. I think there is some issue woth this code     var innercoutner = $(this).closest('.medication_info').find('.medication_info').children('.row').length+2;

Comment: @Barmar, What I did,  I remove the var addrm and my append code from the success and added var addrm inside click function.  and it's working